# JS Form Verification and INPUT Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

**Please help**

I have a contact form with a working **JS Form Verification** script (code below).

In the form, I need to change **INPUT TYPE** from **TEXT** to **TEL** for ZIP CODE and PHONE NUMBER (If i use TEL, it will open a NUM PAD on mobile devices vs. QWERTY)

**Example:** change `<input type="text">` to `<input type="TEL">`

If I do so, the verification breaks for that field, while works in others. So the way I see it, it's the JS script that does not understand the new Input Type.

The word "TEXT" is mentioned in the script 3 times (beginning, middle and end of script. I tried changing TEXT to TEL, but it did not work.

**Thank you very much for any help!**

**Here is the verification script:**

```
// Validation v5.0
var Validation = { version: '5.0' };

Validation.observe = function() {
  var fields = $('[data-validate]');
  fields.each(function(_,field) {
    field = $(field);
    var input = field.is('input') ? field : field.find('input');
    // console.log('observing ' + input.attr('id'));
    input.bind('keyup focusout click', function() { Validation.validate(field); });
    if ((input.is(':text') && input.val()) || input.is(':checked, :selected')) input.trigger('focusout');
  });
};


Validation.formats = {
  zip:    { format:'^\\d{5}$', message:'need a 5 digit zip' },
  phone:  { format:'^\\s*\\(?\\s*\\d{3}\\s*[).-]?\\s*\\d{3}\\s*[.-]?\\s*\\d{4}\\s*$', message:'need a 10 digit number' },
  email:  { format:'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.+]+)@((\\[ [0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$', message:'need a valid email' }
};

// mainly just sets up variables and passes along to the right validator
Validation.validate = function(element, fireEvent) {
  // console.log('validate()');
  var field, format, message, result, validation, validator;
  field       = $(element);
  Validation.clearError(field);
  format      = field.attr('data-format');
  message     = field.attr('data-error-message');
  validation  = field.attr('data-validate');
  validator   = Validation.validators[validation];
  result      = validator ? validator({ field:field, format:format, message:message }) :
                Validation.validators.unknown(validation);
  field.data('valid', result);
  if (fireEvent !== false) field.trigger('validation:' + (result ? 'success' : 'failure'));
  return result;
};

Validation.validators = {};

// validate the presence of the specified element, displaying an error message if it is invalid
Validation.validators.presence = function(params) {
  // console.log('validators.presence()');
  field   = $(params.field);
  message = params.message || 'required';

  if (field.is('input')) {
    if (!field.val()) return Validation.addError(field, message);
  } else if (!field.find(':checked, :selected').length) {
    return Validation.addError(field.find('input').last(), message);
  }
  return true;
};

// validate the given format of the specified element, displayin an error message if it is invalid
Validation.validators.format = function(params) {
  // console.log('validators.format()');
  field   = $(params.field);
  format  = new RegExp(params.format);
  message = params.message || 'invalid format';

  if (field.is(':text') && !format.test(field.val())) {
    return Validation.addError(field, message);
  }
  return true;
};


// shortcut to validate a zip-code format
Validation.validators.zip = function(params) {
  // console.log('validators.zip()');
  var zip = Validation.formats.zip;
  params.format   = zip.format;
  params.message  = params.message || zip.message;
  return Validation.validators.format(params);
};

// shortcut to validate a phone number format
Validation.validators.phone = function(params) {
  // console.log('validators.phone()');
  var phone = Validation.formats.phone;
  params.format   = phone.format;
  params.message  = params.message || phone.message;
  return Validation.validators.format(params);
};

// shortcut to validate an email format
Validation.validators.email = function(params) {
  // console.log('validators.email()');
  var email = Validation.formats.email;
  params.format   = email.format;
  params.message  = params.message || email.message;
  return Validation.validators.format(params);
};

// if possible, log an unknown validation request
Validation.validators.unknown = function(validator) {
  // console.log('validators.unknown()');
  if (window.console && window.console.log) window.console.log('unknown validator: ' + validator);
  return true;
};

// add an error message to the specified element
Validation.addError = function(field, message) {
  // console.log('addError()');
  $(field).addClass('error').after($('<span class="error_message" />').html(message || 'invalid'));
  return false;
};

Validation.clearError = function(field) {
  field = $(field);
  if (field.is('input')) field.removeClass('error').next('.error_message').remove();
  else field.find('input').removeClass('error').nextAll('.error_message').remove();
};

// check that all fields within a given container which require validation are in fact valid
Validation.allValid = function(container) {
  // console.log('allValid()');
  var haveError = false;
  $(container).find('[data-validate]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('valid') !== true) {
      haveError = true;
    }
  });
  return !haveError;
};

// run all validations within a given container, but don't trigger the validation event
Validation.validateAll = function(container) {
  // console.log('validateAll()');
  $(container).find('[data-validate]').each(function() { Validation.validate(this, false); });
  return Validation.allValid(container);
};

Validation.validateAllWithValue = function(container) {
  //console.log('validateAllWithValue()');
  $(container).find('[data-validate]').each(function() {
    if (($(this).is(':text') && $(this).val()) || $(this).find(':checked, :selected').length) {
      Validation.validate(this, false);
    }
  });
  return Validation.allValid(container);
};


function cmpRejected() {
  $('form').find('.choose_error_message').fadeOut();
  $('#project_info').fadeOut();
  $('#contact_info').fadeIn();
  trackShowContactInfoForm();
}

function cmpBridge() {
  $('#bridge').fadeIn();
  $('#project_info').fadeOut();
  triggerMboxConversion("PDX_mEC_CS_View");
  triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event3", "CS pageviews", false);
  $('#bridge_container .all_wrap .cs_box').click(function() {
    triggerMboxConversion("PDX_mEC_CMP_CS_Xfer");
    triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event4", "CS mEC", true, false); // Passing false as the last argument means this won't actually trigger the event, since SC automatically does that when clicking a link to an external site.
  });
}

$ (function (){
  var has_submit = false;
  $('#back_button').click(function() {
     triggerMboxConversion("PDX_LF_Exit_Back");
     triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event8", "LF Exit", false);
     $('#project_info .main-button').val('Continue').css({opacity:'1.0',filter:'alpha(opacity=100)'}).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#project_info').slideDown();
     $('#contact_info').fadeOut();
  });

  $('#contact_info').find('.submit_step').click(function() {
    if(!has_submit){
      $('form').submit();
    }
  });

  $('.noThanks .CloseLink').click(function() {
    triggerMboxConversion("PDX_mEC_CMP_CS_Exit_No");
    triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event6", "CS Exit No", false);
    $('#contact_info').fadeIn();
    trackShowContactInfoForm();
    $('#bridge').fadeOut();
  });

  $('#close_button').click(function() {
    triggerMboxConversion("PDX_mEC_CMP_CS_Exit_Close");
    triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event5", "CS Exit Close", false);
    $('#contact_info').fadeIn();
    trackShowContactInfoForm();
    $('#bridge').fadeOut();
  });

  $('form').submit(function(){
    if (Validation.validateAll( $(this).find('fieldset:visible') )) {
      if($(this).find('fieldset:visible').is('#contact_info')){
        has_submit = true;
        triggerMboxConversion("PDX_LF_Completion");
        triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event9", "LF Submit", false);
        trackULead( trackingPixelTrade() );
        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').val('submitting...').css({opacity:'0.5',filter:'alpha(opacity=50)'}).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $('#step_2_zip').html($('.enterzip').val());
        $('#project_info .main-button').val('loading...').css({opacity:'0.5',filter:'alpha(opacity=50)'}).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        triggerMboxConversion("PDX_rEC");
        triggerSiteCatalystEvent("event1", "rEC", false);
        checkCMPStepOne($(this));
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  Validation.observe();
});
```

Comment: What libraries are you using? When I try this, I get an error that triggerMboxConversion is not defined. Can you make a fiddle or something?

Comment: But could you make a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) or whatever?

Comment: Mr Lister, no, I can't. I don't know JS, or what those libraries are or do. The form in question works with jquery.min.js, and I just need to add NUMERIC keypad on mobile (hence change Input Type).

Comment: You don't have to know JS to use jsFiddle, you only have to put in a snippet of the HTML you're using, this JS and indicate which libraries you're using; which version of jQuery etc. Like I said, I can't make it work, but I don't know what your environment is. You do.